# Unable to set focus on ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

Im trying to programatically set focus on a `ListView` (ideally the first item in the listview) but even if i try and set focus to just the `ListView` it fails.

Nested XAML (pseudo):

```
 <flipview>
     <listview>
         <listviewitem (template binding)/>
     </listview>
 </flipview>
```

both flipview and listview is set with `IsEnabled="true" IsTabStop="true"`.

trying to set focus using `listview1.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`

setting the focus to the flipview works and returns true but if i try and setting the focus on to the listview it fails and returns false.

Can anyone help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post actual XAML instead of "pseudo", we can't see if you made an error in your actual XAML.

Comment: How do you know you failed setting focus on `ListView`? I just tested your code, `GotFocus` event is triggered by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, the control was refusing to allow focus while the control visibility is set to collapsed.